# Symfony 2 GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle

Tags: symfony, websocket

I'm working in a symfony 2 application and I need to use websocket.

I found a bundle named GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle and I integrate it in the system. This bundle is based on JDare/ClankBundle but the firth has the TopicPeriodicTimerInterface using for resend the information for the client every a defined time.

I have it in my application but I need to get the logged user. The bundle has a service named @gos_web_socket.websocket.client_manipulator to manipulate the user information but when I try to get user information only the service get me the anonymous user but I'm logged for someone user.

Any had the same problem or know a solution for that???

Answer (score 2):

I invite you to follow the procedure for session sharing and user authentication, as explained in the doc of the bundle you use: https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/SessionSetup.md

First you need to implement a Symfony session handler, if you decide to use the PDO Session Handler, the doc is here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html (Do not forget to create the corresponding DB if you chose so, declaring all the services, parameters, and so on).

Next, you have to set your config.yml to use your session handler:

```
framework:
    ...
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.pdo # adapt if you chose a different one
```

Setup GOS Websocket for using it as well:

```
gos_web_socket:
    ...
    client:
        firewall: main # the name of your firewall (can be an array if multiple)
        session_handler: @session.handler.pdo
```

The end of the documentation available at the first link will show you some ways of using your client manipulator. I know it is better to copy paste, but I really don't feel like copy pasting the entire doc is useful, nor clear.

For my own use, I do not have a client manipulator, I simply use

```
$this->clientStorage->getClient($connection->WAMP->clientStorageId);
```

in order to retrieve the user with the current connection. The `clientStorage` is available if you give it (`@gos_web_socket.client_storage`) to the service constructor as argument. Of course, you need to adapt your constructor:

```
class AcmeTopic implements TopicInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ClientStorageInterface $clientStorage
     */
    protected $clientStorage;

    public function __construct(ClientStorageInterface $clientStorage)
    {
        ...
```

To access other users, you can take some inspiration from:

```
foreach($topic as $subscriber)
{
    $subscriber->event($topic->getId(),
                    ['msg' => $this->clientStorage
                                   ->getClient($connection->WAMP->clientStorageId)
                                   ->getUsername().' is now online!']);
}
```

Hope this helps, I do not have that much experience with it, as it is my first use as well. I invite you to ask directly on the GitHub if you are still stuck (issues part), as the author can probably help you more!

(Also, I assumed you use the Topic)

Comment: this will just give the same results back as using directly the manipulator .. an anonymous user, even if logged in.

Comment: Did you try? I successfully get the logged in user doing so.

Comment: Yes I tried, I am just getting back an anonymous User. Did you read the edit I made in the question above? I think this is a cookie problem, could you please post your config (ports, domain etc)

Comment: I access my website using localhost.local. Then, my websocket server runs on localhost.local:8080. Make sure your webserver and the websocket server both run on the same domain, as cookies will not be readable.
Then, I specified: "I do not have a client manipulator...", the `@gos_web_socket.client_storage` service is enough for me. Maybe there is a thing.
Last but not least, make sure to restart the websocket server after each change, if you have the cache, empty it, and so on.
Have you implemented the topic example available on the github? If none of the above work, give it a try to compare!

Comment: I posted a new , related question here with all my configurations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872331/symfony-websockets-logged-user-always-returns-anonym-within-topic

Comment: I found the cause, can't explain it though. Maybe you should have a look at what i've written in the other post on top (with yellow background).

Comment: As said, the webserver and the websocket have to both run on the same domain. By accessing your website via "localhost", you do not allow your websocket server to read the cookie expected to be destined to the 127.0.0.1 address. Cookies are restricted in their access to the domain they have been written from. So to run your website using "localhost", run your websocket server on "localhost" as well.
(However the answer in your other question is wrong, servers cannot run on the same port)

Comment: ok nice, thanks. Will this be a problem in production ? I mean you can access a site by entering "abc.com" or the ip address of the site ? I think I need to redirect users that access my site by entering the ip address to "abc.com"..? Regards.

Comment: Please have a look there to my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32897235/4495909 . I have no clue if accessing the website by its IP will cause the same trouble, it should not, as long as the server and the cookie are well set, however it needs further testing to be sure. A quick check as you said could do the trick as well. If one of the post answered your question, then consider marking it as the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation and got the logged in user.
If you follow all the configuration steps, now tries to access the IP of your application (127.0.0.1) ex: http://127.0.0.1/app_dev.php/chat/
I used to acces with my domain name (http://mydominename/app_dev.php/chat/) and and I did't get the logged user in GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle.

My code:

```
use Gos\Bundle\WebSocketBundle\Topic\TopicInterface;
use Gos\Bundle\WebSocketBundle\Client\ClientManipulatorInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Wamp\Topic;
use Gos\Bundle\WebSocketBundle\Router\WampRequest;    
class ChatTopic implements TopicInterface
{
    protected $clientManipulator;

/**
 * @param ClientManipulatorInterface $clientManipulator
 */
public function __construct(ClientManipulatorInterface $clientManipulator)
{
    $this->clientManipulator = $clientManipulator;
}

public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $connection, Topic $topic, WampRequest $request)
{
    var_dump($this->clientManipulator->getClient($connection)); //To show in WebSocket console.
    /** Rest of code **/
}
```

Do not forget to add a new argument to the service

```
myclass_name.chat_topic:
    class: MyBundle\Topic\ChatTopic
    tags:
        - { name: gos_web_socket.topic }
        arguments: [ @gos_web_socket.websocket.client_manipulator ]
```

This can be a start to your solution.